Does how long you apply a voltage to an aluminum electrolytic capacitor influence the time it can be stored safely?
I read that aluminum electrolytic capacitors stored without being energized for a long time present many types of failures
Does the energization time of the aluminum electrolytic capacitor influence the time it can be stored without being energized safely? For example, I energize the aluminum electrolytic capacitor for 30 minutes vs. another aluminum electrolytic capacitor I energize for 60 minutes, can both be stored for the same amount of months or years? For the same temperature and same humidity, for example, 35C 58-67%

Longer energization allows the oxide layer to stabilize more fully, but the rate of improvement decreases significantly after the first 30 minutes. Like I expect the average effect of 30mins vs 60 mins to be around 10% longer storage time.
It's more important what you do during and after storage.
A Reforming period every couple months would have way more impact.

in my conditions 1 hour in 12 months is acceptable?

How long it works more depends on the make quality of the cap. A high quality cap will have longer storage time without energizing, even,  than a bad one that got 60mins.
So I can't tell. But generally 12 months shouldn't be an issue for average quality caps.
